# View underlying SOAP message using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, soap, service

I have a VB.NET web service that calls a third party web service.  How can I view the SOAP message generated by .NET before it is sent to the third party web service and how can I see the SOAP response before it is serialized by .NET.

When creating a standalone EXE, I see the Reference.vb file that is automatically generated, but don't see a similar file when my project is a web service.  I have found lots of C# code to do this, but none in VB.NET.

Edit - Fiddler and TCP loggers are great, but will not work for my purposes.  I need to be able to access the raw SOAP messages from within the application so I can log them or modify them.  I need to do more than just see the messages going back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fiddler or a tcp sniffer to filter and identify all outgoing and incoming traffic on your host.

This is if you want to see the xml request and response.

Comment: I'd like to be able to access the raw SOAP messages from within .NET so I can log them or modify them.

Comment: Yes get fiddler, with the new .net webservices (WCF) fiddler may not be able to detect the traffic if using tcp communication, so use a tcp sniffer to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an extension to allow you to examine the SOAP message?

Accessing Raw SOAP Messages in ASP.NET Web Services
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188761.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and this seems to work for me:

```
Dim message As String = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()
```

I didn't think it would be that easy since most of the time `ToString()` returns the name of the class, but I tried it out and low and behold.

I know you asked this back in January so if since then you've figured out a better way let me know.

Please note that if you're catching the exception in a class that implements `IErrorHandler` then you have to perform this operation from within the `ProvideFault()` method instead of the `HandleError()` method because the context is closed before it gets to call the `HandleError()` method.

Hope this helps.